# Profile provider for ASP.NET Web App - Auto wired properties

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, asp.net-profiles

In an ASP.NET website it is possible with a few short additions to the Web.Config section to add auto-magically wired properties to the user profile.

So for example with some XML like this.

```
<profile>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
  </providers>
  <properties>
    <add name="Name" allowAnonymous="true"/>
    <add name="VisitedOn" type="System.DateTime" allowAnonymous="true"/>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

You would end up with the ability to do this. Without having to declare any further code.

```
Profile.Name = "Some Test Value";
Profile.VisitedOn = DateTime.Now;
Profile.Save();
```

I have attempted to duplicate this functionality in an ASP.NET Web App and can't even seem to find the base Profile declaration let alone the custom properties.

I have however found that `System.Web.Profile.DefaultProfile.Properties` does infact contain the custom declared properties I define in the Web.Config.

So where might I be going wrong? What is the process for getting auto wired properties in web apps working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The properties are created during the Compilation of ASP.NET Web Application when the first request arrives.

Ref: [ASP.NET Application Life Cycle Overview for IIS 5.0 and 6.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx)

> Profile properties defined in the Web.config file If profile
>   properties are defined in the application's Web.config file, an
>   assembly is generated that contains a profile object.

You can hook into this Compilation by writing a custom [BuildProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.buildprovider) and registering the same. This build provider can be used for generating the auto wired properties.